# How can I get the request parameter and return django rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I fetch the API like with this code

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/mytexts/?genre=93`

```
class MyTextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyText
        fields = ('id','text','genre')
```

it returns `id` `text` `genre` successfully.

then now, I want to return the fetch value `93` or `genre=93` in json.

So,I altered the code, but can't figure out yet..

```
class MyTextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fetchBy = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyText
        fields = ('id','text','genre','fetchBy)
    def get_fetchBy: # error 'MyTextSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_fetchBy'
        return ????
```

Answer (score 2):

DRF's class based view pass request object to serializer with additional [context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) by default. You can access this context using `self.context` syntax. So to fetch query param inside serializer you can do something like this:

```
class MyTextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fetchBy = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyText
        fields = ('id','text','genre','fetchBy')

    def get_fetchBy(self, obj):
        return self.context["request"].query_params.get("genre")
```

Not related to your actual question but one small remark about variable naming. Please note that according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) class's methods and attributes names should be lowercased and use `_` as separator. For example: `fetch_by` and `get_fetch_by`.